# Dealing with timeout exceptions and time.sleep in Urllib2 + pool.map

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, urllib2

I am new to python and I wrote some code to download data from a Web API. However, there are some restrictions that I am obliged to observe when using the API:

- 1 request per second per API key
- If a timeout occurs, wait 30 seconds before trying again
- Limit of 100k requests per day per API key

The code for the method that makes the request to the Web API is:

```
def getMatchDetails(self,match_id):
    '''Calls the WEB Api and requests the data for the match with
    a specific id (in match_id). Then returns the data already decoded 
    from json.'''
    import urllib2
    import json
    import time
    url = self.__makeUrl__(api_key= self.api_key, parameters = ['match_id='+str(match_id)])
    # Sometimes a time out occurs, we keep trying
    while True:
        try:
            start = time.time()
            json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            end = time.time()
            if end - start < 1:
                time.sleep(1 - (end - start))
        except:
            print('Timed Out, Trying again in 30 seconds')
            time.sleep(30)
            continue
        else:
            break
    detailed_data = json.load(json_obj)
    return detailed_data
```

The method **makeUrl** simply concatenates some strings and returns them.
And in order to change the API keys each time the above method is called, I use:

```
def getMatchDetailsForMap(self,match_id):
    self.counter += 1
    self.api_key = self.api_keys[self.counter%len(self.api_keys)]
    return self.getMatchDetails(match_id)
```

Where self.api_keys is a list containing all my API keys.
I then use the method **getMatchDetailsForMap** with the map function in the following code:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
pool = ThreadPool(14)
ids_to_get = self.__idsToGetChunks__(14)
for chunk in ids_to_get:
        results = pool.map(self.getMatchDetailsForMap,chunk)
```

The method **idsToGetChunks** returns a lits of lists (chunks) with parameters (match_id) that are fed to the getMatchDetailsForMap method.

Questions:

- Experimenting with the code, I realized that the 1 second limit per key was not holding; Why is that?
- When a timeout occurs, it really slows the process of getting the data; Are there better ways to deal with that kind of exception when using map? (tips please)

Thanks for reading and helping! Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

To comply with the three requirements, I suggest writing a simple `for` loop, doing one request per loop.  Generally, wait one second.  If a timeout occurs, wait for 30 seconds.  Don't loop more than 100k times.  (I'm assuming this script would run once a day, and would take less than 24 hours ;)  )

The main program fires up one `Process` per API key.

Simple!

### source

```
# 1 request per second per API key
# If a timeout occurs, wait 30 seconds before trying again
# Limit of 100k requests per day per API key

import logging, time, urllib2
import multiprocessing as mp

def do_fetch(key, timeout):
    return urllib2.urlopen(
        'http://example.com', timeout=timeout
    ).read()

def get_data(api_key):
    logger = mp.get_logger()
    data = None
    # Limit of 100k requests per day per API key
    for num in range(100*1000): 
        t = 1 if num!=1 else 0 # test timeout exception
        try:
            data = do_fetch(api_key, timeout=t)
            logger.info('%d bytes', len(data))
        except urllib2.URLError as exc:
            logger.error('exc: %s', repr(exc))
            # If a timeout occurs, wait 30 seconds before trying again
            time.sleep(3)
        else:
            # "1 request per second per API key"
            time.sleep(1)


mp.log_to_stderr(level=logging.INFO)
keys = [123, 234]
pool = mp.Pool(len(keys))
pool.map( get_data, keys )
```

### output

```
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] 1270 bytes
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] 1270 bytes
[ERROR/PoolWorker-2] exc: URLError(error(115, 'Operation now in progress'),)
[ERROR/PoolWorker-1] exc: URLError(error(115, 'Operation now in progress'),)
[INFO/PoolWorker-2] 1270 bytes
[INFO/PoolWorker-1] 1270 bytes
```